# ¿Cómo sumar una variable de un POST a una base de datos?

Tags: php, html, sql, post, insert

Mi duda es la siguiente, yo tengo en mi base de datos una tabla llamada articulos, la cuál tiene varias columnas entre tantas, estan:

> cod_articulo,nombre, descripcion, unidad, grupo y stock

Supongo que del artículo 'Carpetas' tengo 10 en stock el cual aparece en la base de datos, pero hoy viene un proveedor y me trae 100 carpetas, y las quiero agregar al sistema, yo tengo mi **INSERT** que seria el siguiente:

```
$sqlInsert  = "INSERT INTO articulos(cod_articulo, nombre, descripcion, unidad, grupo, stock) VALUES ('".$cod_articulo."', '".$_POST['nombre']."', '".$_POST['descripcion']."', '".$_POST['unidad']."', '".$_POST['grupo']."', '".$_POST['cantidad']."')";
```

En mi POST,  es decir en mi formulario HTML, tengo la variable cantidad que seria la cual quiero usar grabar las 100 carpetas nuevas.
¿Está bien asi el INSERT o como tendría que ser?

Comment: Si el articulo ya existe, que no tendria que ser `UPDATE` en lugar de `INSERT`?

Comment: La lógica de tu `insert` está mal, si la carpeta ya estuviera en la `BD` y tuvieras 3 en existencia, al meter esos 100 que te llevó tu proveedor deberían quedar 103, no solo 100. Lo primero que tienes que hacer es saber si existe el `artículo`, si es así obtienes su inventario actual y solo le sumas lo que te lleve tu proveedor, si no existe solo es cuestión de agregarlo con los datos que te envía tu formulario.

Comment: @EmmanuelHD Quizás, quizás entendiste mal lo que quise decir o quizás lo escribí mal yo. Me refería a que grabara las 100 carpetas nuevas. Obviamente, quedaría en 110. Y en cuanto a la comprobación de si existe el archivo, ya lo tengo en el código, pero no era eso lo que quería saber, de igual formas. Gracias

Comment: @alanfcm De ser con un [UPDATE] como quedaría el código final?

Comment: Creo que no te diste a entender, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y pongas todo el código que mencionas que ya compruebas. Por que tu `Insert` solo agrega lo que recibe por `Post`, nunca veo la suma. Así podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @EmmanuelHD la pregunta se entiende. ¿Cómo sumo una variable del código o de un POST, sí lo prefieres así, a la Base de Datos? Alan entendió la pregunta, aunque yo no entiendo como sería el código que el quiere que ponga. Y no ves la suma, porque justamente esa es mi duda ¿Cómo formular o escribir la suma?

Comment: @AgustinAvila, si se entiende, pero no entendemos lo que tu entiendes, en mi primer comentario ya te expuse lo que debes hacer, dijiste que que ya compruebas si existe el producto, sube ese código y vemos en que fallas, aquí no se resuelven los problemas, se ayuda a resolver los errores después de haber intentado resolver el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te llega el proveedor con N cantidad de carpetas y quieres sumarlas al stock, primero haz un SELECT a ese campo para saber cuántas carpetas tienes:

```
$sql = "SELECT stock FROM articulos WHERE nombre = 'Carpetas'"; /* aqui tendrías que agregar la condición para determinar de que articulo quieres traer su cantidad.
$query = mysqli($con, $sql);
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if($resultado['stock'] > 0){
$cantidad_Total = $resultado['stock'] + $_POST['cantidad'];
$update = "UPDATE articulos set stock = '$cantidad_Total' WHERE stock = '$resultado['stock']'";
mysqli($con, $update);
else{
/* aqui pones tu insert original ya que vas a insertar cuando el campo este vacio o valga 0*/
}
```

Espero te funcione.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Vick Muñoz

Comment: De nada, espero si te haya aclarado la duda :)